# Best way to develop cross platform mobile device app with QT?

Tags: qt, mobile

We have a basic data entry app we want to develop using QT as the development platform. There appears to be Qt Mobility and QT Web Kit. The goal is to have the app run on as many mobile phone platforms as possible.

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure that your approach will work for anything but Qt-based mobile OS platforms (Symbian I believe, and maybe a few others).

Most mobile OS platforms are NOT language-neutral for native applications, so if you want to develop for iPhone you'll need to use Objective-C, Android and BBOS will require Java, etc...

Also, many platforms will require you to use their platform-specific APIs to access hardware, so even if you *could* build a cross-platform mobile app in C++ using Qt you wouldn't be able to get access to any hardware on the device.

Then again, if it's a web app, why not just develop it for the browser (ie: use standard web technologies)?

Comment: +1 for recommending a web app. Qt currently runs on Symbian and just Symbian. The other would be MeeGo, but MeeGo is just a promise, right now.

Comment: We are looking at a JQuery mobile site instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Brian says all.

All Mobile platforms are not same, so if you build an app using Qt, then you can run it on Symbian and Meego (mobile platform from Nokia) devices, where as Meego is not restricted to mobiles, it is targeted for In-Vehicle devices, Notebooks etc, please refer www.meego.com for more information.

--Cheers